# copying a string

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I can use only `<iostream>` and `<string>` headers. (I am using C++)

I will read input from a text and convert it to lowercase type. I read the input and convert it to lowercase but i have a problem. It reads-converts everything properly but when I print it, there is no space between them. I should copy every "word" in a string and count the all words. How can I do it? Can you help me?

I used this algorithm to convert to lowercase:

```
if('A'<=s[i] && s[i]<='Z') 
    s[i]=s[i]+'a'-'A';
```

And how can I copy this words one by one into another string?

Comment: Let's see some code...

Comment: Could you show your code, please!

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are using `operator >>` to read your input into `std::string`. This effectively removes all whitespace from your input, because you go through it word-by-word.

You need to use a whitespace-preserving method of input, such as [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). It would also read the input into `std::string`, but spaces would be preserved:

```
for (std::string line ; std::getline(input, line) ;) {
    // Convert line to lowercase, and write the result
}
```

> now it can't see the new lines

Since `std::getline` does not preserve newline characters, you need to put them back yourself while writing out the output. For example, like this:

```
std::cout << lowercaseString << std::endl
```

Comment: I want to add to this: When converting to lowercase using this method, watch out not to try to convert spaces, as this will lead to surprising results

Comment: @MivVG: well, it really depends from how you convert to lowercase... `tolower` leaves intact anything that it doesn't consider a letter, so you can blindly apply it on any character without risks (making sure to convert to `unsigned char` beforehand).

Comment: @MatteoItalia OP mentioned that he's not using headers other than `string` and `iostream`, which suggests that he must be doing his `tolower` manually.

Comment: Thank you but now it can't see the new lines

Comment: True, but he can't use `std::tolower` as he may only include `string`and `iostream`

Comment: I didn't use tolower, teacher said we can't use it. My algorithm is this:
if('A'<=s[i] && s[i]<='Z')
           s[i]=s[i]+'a'-'A';

Comment: Aah sorry didn't read carefully enough. Yes, it's safe (although not completely portable, but honestly who cares about EBCDIC anymore).

Comment: You have quite the typo in your code. It should be `for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line);) {`, or else the compiler thinks it's a range-based for loop, which fails.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thanks! It looks like Matteo's edit that went wrong :-)